# Using =ROW() command as a Cell Number when referencing another cell in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm pretty new to excel and it's functions and I have this problem:
I'm trying to create a formula that if copied in a different row automatically locks it's internal reference to a cell in the same row.

This is the code I'm stuck with: `=(I59-$n$59)*(I59-$N$59)`
but when I copy this formula in another row it maintains the same row references,
I'm trying to use the =ROW() function to replace the hardcoded numbers, I tried different variations of this:
`=(IROW()-$n$ROW())*(IROW()-$N$ROW())`
But it doesn't recognise the row command as text or as a part of the calling reference, any ideas would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDEX`:

```
=(INDEX(1:1048576,ROW(),COLUMN($I:$I))-INDEX(1:1048576,ROW(),COLUMN($N:$N)))^2
```

Another option is `INDIRECT`, but it is a volatile formula and really should be avoided if possible:

```
=(INDIRECT("I"&ROW())-INDIRECT("N"&ROW()))^2
```

Another option using the implicit intersection operator:

```
=(@I:I-@N:N)^2
```

Comment: Yes agree, Ï will definitely use the `INDEX()` one.

Comment: In this case where the row is the actual row we could use intersection reference using `@`: `=(@I:I-@N:N)^2` but I think your answer is more useful, since you could tweak the row to reference a previous or next row.

Answer (score -1):

Remove $ symbol before n (row reference)
=(I59-n$59)*(I59-N$59)

Comment: My main point is to use the ROW() command to remove the hardcoded "59" from the place "N$59", so instead of having 59 I always have the number of the current row referenced